# Trying to replace Pip with Conda in a conda template repo

Tags: pip, gitlab, conda

Working in a conda template repo on GitLab. Looking to replace pylint with flake8 in the gitlab CI, and install using conda instead of pip. Swap pip install flake8 with conda install flake8 and getting ther erroe that @command conda not found" after I push and view the pipeline. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conda like this in Gitlab

```
image: continuumio/miniconda3:latest

before_script:
  - conda env create -f environment.yml
  - source activate koopa

tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - python -m unittest discover -v
```